# Mathematica typesetting (writing in Text cells) PROBLEMS - unpredictable behaviour!

Tags: front-end, formatting

I've been using Mathematica for years.  Even the latest v.13 is still giving really weird behaviour when writing in a Text cell, and completely unexpectedly:

- Changes unexpectedly the text *style*, text *size*, text *colour* (I use text colour to accentuate)
- Even when having selected a word, typing to *replace* it, it will change the font *style/size/colour*
- Difficulty with *alignment* of next line to previous (it predicts tabbing but *not aligning*)

I know it's not LaTeX, but surely we should be able to expect consistency, and not erratic runaway behaviour!  And this has been going on for *years*.  Hardly any attempt at all has been made to make the front-end *text*-writing much easier and bug-free!!

Has anyone come up with a solution or work-around please?
I would really appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: _Has anyone come up with a solution or work-around please?_  I never used Mathematica this way. It is a losing battle to try to use Mathematica for your final report layout. Maplesoft have same problems. These commerical companies waste so many resources trying to make their documents look nice, but at the end it will never work. Notebooks are meant for computation and programming. Not for final presentation. The way I always done this is generate the Latex from the notebook at the end, and use Latex to make my final report. This always works and the best solution for me,

Comment: I use Text cells and DisplayFormula cells often when gathering my work and although there are some limitations, I do not encounter the problems you describe although I don't color-code anything.   I use exclusively, the Standard Report style sheet for all my notebooks.  Maybe you can try changing to this style sheet and see if there are improvements.  Choose Format/Stylesheet/Report/Standard Report

Comment: Without steps to repro what you're seeing, all I can say is I've never seen what you describe. It is definitely true that MMA notebooks do not support the same styling as professional publishing applications. However, I used MMA for years to format training materials as booklets. As long as I stayed within some constraints (which I rarely found particularly egregious), and as long as I was willing to use stylesheets extensively, it actually worked well.

Comment: If you can give clear steps to replicate the issues then it would be useful to have them reported as bugs.

Comment: I have never seen the this and I have 13.0.